# Reporting on changes before the end of an ActiveRecord transaction commits. (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, transactions

I am doing a complex series of database interactions within nested transactions using `ActiveRecord` (Rails), involving various `model.update(...)`, `model.where(...).first_or_create(..)` etc

Right before the transaction ends I'd like to report on what's actually changed and about to be written.  Presumably `ActiveRecord` holds this information but I've not been able to work out where.

My code would be something like (**semi-pseudocode**)

```
def run options
  begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do |tranny|
    options[:files].each do |file|
      raw_data = open(file)
      complex_data_stuff raw_data, options
    end
    report
  rescue => e
    "it all went horribly wrong, here's why: #{e.message}"
  end
end

def report tranny
  changes = {}
  tranny.whatschanged?.each do |ch|
    changes[ch.model.class.name] = {} unless changes[ch.model.class.name]
    if changes[ch.model.class.name][ch.kind_of_update]
      changes[ch.model.class.name][ch.kind_of_update] += 1
    else
      changes[ch.model.class.name][ch.kind_of_update] = 1
    end
  end
  changes
end
```

How would I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

This is the latest version of "dirty models", which keeps track of the differences between the current object and the saved version.  You access the changes via a "changes" method like in your attempt.

I added some extra stuff in one of my projects to store what was changed in the last update:  this is stored in an instance variable, so is only accessable in the specific object in memory (ie you can't see it if you reload it from the database).

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    attr_accessor :changed_in_last_save
    before_save :set_changed_in_last_save_hash

    def set_changed_in_last_save_hash
      self.changed_in_last_save_hash = self.changes
    end

    def changed_in_last_save
      self.changed_in_last_save_hash || {}
    end
  end
end
```

You definitely need ActiveModel::Dirty, you probably don't need my thing, just mentioned it as it's similar :)

Comment: Your way is how I am thinking of doing it, but with some tweaks.  I looked at `ActiveModel::Dirty` but I'd still need to keep track of which models and instances of those models have changed; not something I can do from the `run` method. I'm not interested in which attributes have changed, only counting which models have been created and which have been updated.

Comment: Ah i see.  We use another system for that - have a look at https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited